# Group by and Distinct gets me only unique ones for each group

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I'm using group by and I use count distinct to count unique ids but it only counts unique ids for  each group. I want to count if that id was not count in another group.

Comment: Please show your query, some input, the expected output from that input and the current output ... Ie create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: .... Count distinct to count unique ids but it only counts unique ids for each group ????? So you don't want it to do what you want it to do?

Comment: I already count unique ids in each group but I also need another column that shows the number of unique ids compared to all table, these ids shouldn't be counted in another groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *, count() over (partition by id1) as id1cnt
    from T
)
select id2, count(case when id1cnt = 1 then 1 end) cnt
from data
group by id2
```